# Deriving equality with algebra?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone walk me through computation of the following equality?

$$\frac{1}{i}\int \frac{dz}{z(a + \frac{z + z^{-1}}{2})^2} = \frac{4}{i}\int \frac{zdz}{(z^2 + 2az + 1)^2}$$

I've gotten as far as:

$$\frac{4}{i}\int \frac{dz}{4z(a^2 + a(z + z^{-1}) + z^2 + z^{-2} + 2)}$$

but am unsure of how to proceed after this.

Thanks.

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by $4z$. Then pull the $4z^2 = (2z)^2$ into the parenthesis in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{i}\int\frac{dz}{z(a+\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2})^2}=\frac{1}{i}\int\frac{4dz}{z(2a+z+z^{-1})^2}=\frac{1}{i}\int\frac{4dz}{z\frac{(2az+z^2+1)^2}{z^2}}=\frac{4}{i}\int\frac{zdz}{(2az+z^2+1)^2}$$